# Suitable image aspect ratio for container which doesn't have a fixed width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, image-size, responsive-images

I don't know much about aspect ratios which is why I need some help today.

**The Issue**

I have been creating an 'about the team' page and have had some photo's taken however the photographer wants to know which aspect ratio the photo's should be edited to. I have no clue what is a good aspect ratio for my purpose.

**Context and information**
An example of what the bootstrap card design looks like : 
https://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/Lx1gs0pk/

Basically this is the type of code we are looking at :

```
  <div class="card">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap" style="width: 100%;height:150px;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Apologies I am unable to add my own code therefore I have provided examples.*

The height of the image is 150px however the width is 100% to fill the container.

The container's width changes depending on screen width so there can either be 1 card on the screen (mobile) or multiple cards across the screen therefore we dont know the width of the image.

In this scenario when we know the height but we dont know the width, what is the best aspect ratio to go for?

I have been told that normally 4:3 aspect ratio is used.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio belongs to the object. It is originally x width by x height. That creates it's aspect ratio. With the img tag, if you only specify the width OR the height, the other side will scale proportionally. If you specify both (width and height), the image will be displayed at those measurements (this abandons the aspect ratio of the image).

You can use a percentage to determine the width OR the height. So if it's viewed on devices with different aspect ratios, your image will always ONLY use that percent of the screen real estate, while maintaining the image's aspect ratio.

Update: if you're using the images as a background, you have additional options (i.e., contain and cover). Using contain will fit (display) your entire image inside the parent. While using cover will fill the entire parent with image (potentially squeezing or stretching the image).

Hope that helps you to understand the aspect ratio bit.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation however I am still confused as to which aspect ratio is best for the original image. If you had to decide on an aspect ratio for a container that was 150px in height and variable in width would your choice be 4:3 , 16:9 , 1:1 or something else?

Comment: I don't know if your collection of images vary in sizes or if they are all uniform. If they vary, you'll need to decide on which size is more important to you (that is, if you don't want to squeeze and stretch), the width or the height. A 4:3 ratio means that for every 4 inches wide you'll have 3 inches tall (or 1280px width by 960px height) vs 16:9 with same structure but is 1280px width by 720px height. Think of it as 16:9 is the wide format used for cinema movies and 4:3 for tv's.